# Sawdust from treated wood on my lawn

Tags: wood, landscaping, chemicals

Over the weekend I built a playhouse for my kids in the back yard using pressure treated lumber.  As I was cleaning up I realized that my lawn was covered in chemical laden sawdust.  Has anyone here had experience with this?  Is it a problem and if so is there a solution?

Comment: When you say chemical laden, what are you referring to?

Comment: The chemicals used in the pressure treating process.

Comment: I'd just make sure no one is eating the grass. After a few storms, things will quickly break down and get dispersed into the soil. Maybe use a leaf blower to disperse it (wear a dust mask) if there's too much in one location.

Comment: Wait... You're worried about the chemical laden sawdust on your lawn, but what about the chemical laden lumber your children are playing in!?

Comment: Not really.  http://dufferinpark.ca/cityplaygrounds/pdf/ccatreatedwood.pdf

Comment: @BMitch Please do not use comments to answer questions, especially when you are making health and safety claims that cannot be properly vetted as an "answer." Thanks.

Comment: I've used a Dyson bagless vacuum cleaner to get sawdust off my lawn and it worked surprisingly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a big enough pile to make snowballs...or sawdust balls rather.  I wouldn't worry about it.  It shouldn't hurt the grass and again unless the kids are rolling around it it, or licking it you should be just fine.

In the First Aid section of the [MSDS](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic967858.files/ACQ%20Pressure%20Treated%20Wood%20and%20Lumber.pdf), for skin contact it says...

> For skin contact, wash immediately with soap and water. Get medical
>   attention if irritation develops or persists.

The by the book answer is yes follow the MSDS to the letter. But MSDS sheets are written with lawsuits in mind and are generally overzealous in how things should be handled. This is the same reason a piece of stained oak threshold at Lowe's has a "This product has been known to cause cancer in the state of California" sticker on it. I have had ptw dust in my eyes and on my body and had no ill effects. Sure if you have a pile, pick/clean it up, if its scattered...mine is realistic advice, I would not worry about it.

Comment: Can you provide any sources for this information, or is this simply your opinion?

Comment: Yes but the same thing shows up on MSDS sheets for latex paint, I am not saying you should rub either all over your skin but a little sawdust in the yard isn't going to hurt anything.

Comment: I neither agree or disagree. I was just pointing out that the answer would be better with sources to back up your claims.

Comment: Good point, comments moved up to the answer, makes it better, thanks.

Comment: @James: I agree that the sawdust isn't a big deal but I just have to say that your argument that "I did something potentially dangerous and I'm fine" is a really bad way to approach safety issues.

Comment: I wouldn't use the same argument if this were a question say...about running electrical.  Just trying to get across this is not a big deal.

Comment: Well the question is about whether a chemical is or isn't dangerous, so I think the only way to know is to consult an appropriate authority. "I've smoked cigarettes all my life and I'm fine, therefore smoking must be safe."